# MIPS: saving `$ra` to stack for nested functions

Tags: nested, mips

I am new to MIPS and am trying to figure out returning values in nested functions. I am trying to figure out why in the function `test` when I load `$ra` from the stack it takes me to the instruction after I call `calcs` function in `main` instead of to the instruction after `jal test` in `calcs` function? Is a new stack created for every function?

When I am in the `test` function I should have 2 `$ra` values in the stack and when I load the last in `$ra` value it should be the one to return me to the instruction after `jal test` in `calcs` function, but that isn't happening and I can't figure out why.

```
.data
    newline: .asciiz    " XXXX "

.text
main:

    addi $s0, $0, 39        # val 1
    addi $s1, $0, 2         # val 2
    addi $s2, $0, 14        # val 3
    addi $s3, $0, 11        # val 4

    add $a0, $0, $s0        # copy val 1 to $a0
    add $a1, $0, $s1        # copy val 2 to $a1

    jal calcs
    add $s4, $0, $v0        # move returned value to $s4


    # Exit program
    li $v0, 10          # system call to exit program
    syscall


calcs:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4       # make space in stack 
    sw $ra, 0($sp)          # add $ra value to stack

    add $t8, $s0, $a0       # save arg $a0 to $t8
    add $t9, $s0, $a1       # save arg $a1 to $t9

    jal test

    add $t0, $0, $v0        # move returned value to $t0
    add $a0, $0, $v0        # move returned value to $a0

    # print
    li $v0, 1           
    syscall             

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    # get value from stack
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    lw $ra, 0($sp)

    add $v0, $0, $t0

    jr $ra

test:

    addi $sp, $sp, -4       # make space in stack
    sw $ra, 0($sp)          # push $ra value to stack

    add $t0, $0, -989898989
    add $v0, $0, $t0

    #### If I keep the two lines below then the $ra value jumps to be right after I call the calcs function in main. But if I remove it then it goes to the value right after I call the test function in calcs
    lw $ra, 0($sp)          # load $ra value from stack
    addi $sp, $sp, 4        # pop value off stack

    # printing
    add $a0, $0, $t0        
    li $v0, 1           
    syscall             

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    add $v0, $0, $t0        # copy $t0 value to $v0 again

    jr $ra
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on MARS 4.5 and the code seems fine too. Only problem is in calcs: `addi $sp, $sp, 4` and `lw $ra, 0($sp)` should be swapped, but that does not cause your mentioned issue.

Comment: As @Eraklon says, you have two instructions toward the end of `calcs` to pop the return address off the stack, but they are in the wrong order, so it pops the stack first, then fetches the return address from an empty stack, and as a result is unable to return properly to its caller.  Just swap those two instructions and it will run to completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `calcs` you have:

```
addi $sp, $sp, 4
lw $ra, 0($sp)
```

This (incorrect) code sequence will pop the stack and then try to fetch an $ra value from an empty stack.  When I run this, as the empty stack is filled with zeros, so that sequence loads `0` into `$ra`, which causes the program to crash soon after in doing `jr $ra` with zero in `$ra`.

The proper code sequence to pop is to fetch first, then deallocate the stack space.

```
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addiu $sp, $sp, 4
```

> I am trying to figure out why in the function test when I load `$ra` from the stack it takes me to the instruction after I call `calcs` function in `main` instead of to the instruction after `jal test` in `calcs` function?

We don't see this behavior in the code as posted, so it must have happened in some other incarnation you were experimenting with.

*For example, **if you also had that same two-instruction pop-sequence reversed in `test`.** the code would return directly from `test` to `main` (instead of properly returning from `test` to `calcs`, and only then crashing by trying to return to the null address as it does as posted).*

> Is a new stack created for every function?

No, all functions in the thread of the process share the same stack via sharing the stack pointer with each other.  The `$sp` stack pointer is implicitly shared (i.e. as a parameter) with functions as they are called.

> When I am in the test function I should have 2 $ra values in the stack and when I load the last in $ra value it should be the one to return me to the instruction after jal test in calcs function, but that isn't happening and I can't figure out why.

I'm not sure what you mean by last, but once you use a proper pop sequence everywhere, there will be two return addresses on the stack, an older one to return from `calcs` to `main` and the newer one to return from `test` to `calcs`.  As is the nature of the (call) stack, the newer one is used first and then later the older one.

---

As pointers are unsigned, use addiu when you're manipulating them, e.g. when adjusting the $sp.